# Sequence contains no elements even though I add OrDefault

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am getting an error for the life of me I can not resolve.
The error I get is as follows:

> [InvalidOperationException]: Sequence contains no elements    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.ExecuteQuery(NhLinqExpression
>   nhLinqExpression, IQuery query, NhLinqExpression nhQuery)    at
>   NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
>   at NHibernate.Linq.DefaultQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)    at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1
>   source)    at Nichols.Web.Controllers.LoadController.RttInUse(String
>   rttNumber) in
>   c:\projects\NicholsFarms_demo_newCropYear\Nichols\src\Nichols.Web\Controllers\LoadController.cs:line
>   71    at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

and the code I am TRYING to use is:

```
public ActionResult RttInUse(string rttNumber)
{
    int validNumber;
    int recommendRttNumber = 0;
    var cropYear = _session.Query<CropYear>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsCurrent);

    if (cropYear.RttRangeHaveBeenConfiguredForNewCropYear)
    {
        recommendRttNumber = _session.Query<Load>()
            .Where(x =>
                x.CropYear == cropYear &&
                !x.RttNumber.Contains("VOID") &&
                x.RttNumber.Length < 9)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => x.RttNumber)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => int.Parse(x) >= cropYear.RttNumberRangeStart &&
                                 int.Parse(x) <= cropYear.RttNumberRangeEnd).AsInt() + 1;
    }

    if (rttNumber == null || !int.TryParse(rttNumber, out validNumber))
    {
        return AsJson(
            "Rtt number invalid, numeric values only. Next Rtt Number should be " +
            recommendRttNumber);
    }

    var loadExists = _session.Query<Load>()
        .Any(x =>
            x.RttNumber.ToLower() == rttNumber.ToLower() &&
            x.CropYear == cropYear);

    if (loadExists)
    {
        return AsJson("Rtt Number already in use. Next Rtt Number should be " +
                      recommendRttNumber);
    }

    return AsJson(true);
}
```

Basically while operators enter a string such as 150001 on the form, the value they enter is compared against an acceptable range in the database.

Crop year has entries such that the year 2015 has an acceptable range of 150001 to 159999 to choose from which is RttNumberRangeStart to RttNumberRangeEnd; if it is in use, they should get recommended the current used rttnumber + 1.

Comment: Are you actually setting a default value somewhere? How about using the [null coaleasing operator ??](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) together with the `orDefault` statements?

Comment: The Error Dump says you are calling `First()`, not `FirstOrDefault()`.  Is that error dump from the last run?  We could be trying to debug the wrong problem.

Comment: also at which line is the exception occurring?

Comment: It would seem to be at Line 71 where it reads:if (rttNumber == null || !int.TryParse(rttNumber, out validNumber)) {
    return AsJson("Rtt number invalid, numeric values only. Next Rtt Number should be " + recommendRttNumber);
   }

Comment: My range for 2015 is starting at 150000 and ends at 159999. The highest entry I have in the system so far is 151497 so the next recommendation SHOULD be 151498. If I were to use 151497 AGAIN, it should (a) give me a polite message and (b) recommend 151498.

Comment: well that line number just doesn't make sense, there isn't anything about that line that is calling NHibernate's query system.  are you sure you are working with a current build?  have you cleaned your workspace and tested this again?  @JamesCurran may be on the right track there

Comment: Can I rewrite the code to bring it down to basics? All it needs to do is accept a string for the RTTNumber, check to see if its in play and if so recommend a new RTTNumber. Thats it. Obviously if I enter a number that goes outside the start and end range for the crop it can politely say I am out of range...

Comment: I think the first thing you need to do is find the exception using the debugger.  The line number you provided should not throw that exception - run the program using the debugger and step through every line until the exception occurs and examine what the values were of any collections being accessed.  Right now all we can do is tell you that a collection has no data in it, but we can't see the values of anything at runtime.

Comment: be sure to toss a breakpoint inside of any lambda expressions you have written as well as the error points to an issue in one of your lambdas

Answer (score 2):

Probably the sequence below contains no elements:

```
.FirstOrDefault(x => int.Parse(x) >= cropYear.RttNumberRangeStart &&
                     int.Parse(x) <= cropYear.RttNumberRangeEnd)
```

so it cannot do the following on a null (default) element

```
.AsInt() + 1;
```

Assuming `RttNumber` is a `string` and `AsInt()` an extension method to convert an `string` to `int`, change it to return `0` on a null `string`.

Comment: But that would be a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Not if `AsInt` is an extension method. Check this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOxRRc

Comment: Not on the call, but it would be unavoidable in the function.  And it would be accepting a scalar, not a sequence anyway,  Your dotnetfiddle is not causing any error.  But we are looking for the source of an error.  Come back with a Fiddle which cause a non-nullreference exception.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` returns a scalar, not a sequence. And that would be the input of the `AsInt` method.

Comment: Precisely -- yet the error we are seeing refers to a sequence.

Comment: Got it. The way I thought it would throw an `ArgumentNullException` but not the exception OP is getting (updated the Fiddle to reflect it anyway). Guess you're right about the dump/source divergency.